# TwiML: create an automatic navigation & wait before playing the message

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am using `Twilio` to call Shops land-lines and play a message.

Some of the shops are using answering-machine with navigation to a specific departed: "press 3 for customer service..."

I would like to create an automatic navigation: When the system will recognize an answering machine I will use a digits sequence for each shop to reach the right department.

My problem is that after the system finished navigating 
to the right department I don't know how long it will take the person in that department to pickup the phone and only after that to play the message.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
<Play>
   <digits="wwww3">
</play>

<Pause length="?"/>      // I don't know how long to wait.

 <Play>
   https://mySite/message.mp3
</play>
```

Is there an option to know when this person picks up the phone?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy answer. This is why most telemarketing companies use call screening (see below), or just play their message no matter what when someone answers.

Telemarketing is a multi-million dollar industry, and if this type of system was readily available or easy to develop companies would use it, however, they do not.

The only way you can be 100% sure a human has answered the phone and is listening is call screening as explained here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/php/laravel

While not a complete match for your query it is also covered here

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine where it says

One alternative to AMD is Call Screening, aka “Human Detection”.

That is it for easy implementation. Outside of that you could code your own machine that could listen into the call via conference to try to identify when a human speaks and then process it. However, this type of system is very expensive and complex from what I have seen and even then it is not 100% reliable.